# Unable to open Python GUI application

Tags: python, python-gui

I've installed WinPython 32-bit v3.3.5 in my PC and added C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5 to PATH. My python GUI app does not automatically associate with python and 'Open With' is not allowing me to choose python.exe. Running the script directly from command prompt given a error - "Can't find a default python".

Comment: Use the full path to Python when trying to run the script.

Comment: Did you add the folder with `python.exe` to your `PATH` environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

WinPython is a portable application, so the user should not expect any integration into Windows Explorer during [installation](http://sourceforge.net/p/winpython/wiki/Installation/). However, the [WinPython Control Panel](http://sourceforge.net/p/winpython/wiki/ControlPanel/) allows to "register" your distribution to Windows (see screenshot below).

[image: WinPython_Register]

Registering your WinPython installation will:

- associate file extensions .py, .pyc and .pyo to Python interpreter
- register Python icons in Windows Explorer
- add context menu entries `Edit with IDLE` and `Edit with Spyder` for .py files
- register WinPython as a standard Python distribution (standard Python Windows installers will see WinPython in Windows registry)

That is exactly what the official Python installer would do to your machine: in other words, you can have it both ways!

<sub>**Source:** http://winpython.sourceforge.net/</sub>